# Is there a difference between `import a as b` and `import a ; b = a`?

Tags: python, syntax, include, python-import

It's common for me to write in REPL, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Is there a difference between this sentence and

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime
```

? For now I can list two:

- the first sentence is more readable
- the first sentence does not create a `datetime` variable

PS: I'm trying to play with pyPEG for creating a toy parser.

Comment: If you add `del datetime` in the second snippet (and assuming `datetime` wasn't defined beforehand and there is no other thread which could try to access `datetime` in the meantime) it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, you don't do `del datetime` like in the PEP, so `datetime` will remain a valid name, while in the first example, it is not. If you were to run `del datetime`, then they'd be identical.

The `import as` syntax was introduced in [PEP 221](https://peps.python.org/pep-0221/). The second code example you provided is almost the same as the provided rationale for the change:

> This PEP proposes an extension of Python syntax regarding the import and from  import statements. These statements load in a module, and either bind that module to a local name, or binds objects from that module to a local name. However, it is sometimes desirable to bind those objects to a different name, for instance to avoid name clashes. This can currently be achieved using the following idiom:
>
> ```py
> import os
> real_os = os
> del os
> ```

Essentially, `import as` is just syntactic sugar and doesn't do anything else special.